# import mp3 into android eclipse is breaking

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mp3

My issue is that I am importing a mp3 into my android project from eclipse which is causing it to break.  However, if I delete that file (error goes away) and I use a mp3 file that I've used before in a previous project, it doesn't have a compile error.  SO, is this something to do with the mp3 file?  Maybe it was a .WMA file and it was converted to a mp3 file.  So since it isn't a true mp3, it is causing eclipse to break?

Does anybody know a fix, import, plugin or anything else that could allow for multiple music files to be accepted into my android application?

One more thing, I am importing it into the Res/raw path.

Comment: you want to play mp3 file in project ?

Comment: if you want to add .mp3 file in to res folder then no need to IMPORT. just go where your source code is available in local disc. and just copy past mp3 file in to res folder after that go in to eclipse and just refresh your project. now you want to play mp3 file then just give reference that file in to code. you can do this with asset folder also. if you have query then add comment below.

Comment: Yes i am wanting to play the mp3 file in the project which I know how to do. bvanvelsen, I honestly can't remember the error right now.  I should have probably waited to poste this question once I got home and around my computer.  Dhaval, I could, but I think that that will still give me the same error won't it regardless of rather i import it or drag and drop?

Answer (score 1):

What fixed my issue was I took all of the capital letters and spaces out of my music file name and it fixed the issue.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure file name is clean and

- Doesn't start with number
- Doesn't contain spaces
- Doesn't include special characters except '-'

Capital letters are OK.